# Is there something similar to lodash _.toArray for ramda.js?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, lodash, ramda.js

I want to stop using `lodash.js` and switch to `ramda.js` but I don't see any function like `_.toArray()` for objects, is there something like this in `ramda` that I should compose or should I continue using `lodash` for these functions (and possibly more cases that I have not run into yet.)

For example
In `lodash` if you have an Object like :

`{"key1": {"inner": "val"}, "key2" : {"inner": "val"}}`

you can convert it to an array like this:

`[{"inner": "val"}, {"inner": "val"}]`

using the function `_.toArray()`

Comment: `_.toArray() for objects` - Hmmm, can you give a sample?

Comment: IIRC, `_.toArray` doesn't work on plain objects, only array-like objects (NodeList, ArgumentList, etc)

Comment: @simplesthing Nope. It gives only the values, like this `[ { inner: 'val' }, { inner: 'val' } ]` and you can do that with [`values`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#values)

Comment: @thefourtheye you're correct I can edit the example, but the question is the same, is there a compose or function using ramda that I can use?

Comment: Sorry I did not see the values response, thank you @thefourtheye if you move your comment into an answer I can mark it as correct.

Comment: IIRC, `_.toArray` is mostly designed for taking the arguments object and _really_ making it an array so you can pass those as arguments to apply. I don't think it was designed for the purpose above, its probably just coincidental that it works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, Ramda has [`values`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#values), which seems to be what you're looking for:

```
var obj = {"key1": {"inner": "val"}, "key2" : {"inner": "val"}};
R.values(obj); //=> [{"inner": "val"}, {"inner": "val"}]
```

But it's pretty unclear from the [lodash documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#toArray), what kinds of values `_.toArray` function accepts, so this might not be a complete replacement.

Comment: I imagine either [`R.values`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#values) or [`R.toPairs`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#toPairs) is what the OP is after.

Answer (score 2):

Mb vanilla.js will help you? :) ( browser support IE9+ and all other browsers )

```js
var obj = {"key1": {"inner": "val"}, "key2" : {"inner": "val"}};
    
    
var array = Object.keys(obj || {}).map(function(key){
   return obj[key];
});
    
document.write(JSON.stringify(array, null, 4));
```